# Linking within a a webpage

Tags: hyperlink

I was wondering if I were to make a heading, how do I put a link in at the end of the html that would click back to the heading at the top of the page? Also, once I achieve that, how do I put that within an unordered list. The link wouldn’t be for another page or open on another page it would just scroll the website back up the heading.  Would that need an id?

I tried basic linking that you would use for attaching a website and it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

if you just would like to jump to the top of your page, you can do that by using an anchor tag with the page name as href.

For example if your page is called index.html then:

```
<p>Click <a href='index.html' >Here</a> to jump back to the top of the page</p>
```

This will jump to the top of the page without reload. You can embed anchor tags into unordered list items as well the same way

```
<ul>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">click here</a></li>
</ul>
```